# Can use cd-key from retail version of Witcher 3 to download from gog.com or steam?

Tags: the-witcher-3, gog

I've just ordered Witcher 3 for PC from Amazon but I didn't realize that it comes on bluray (at least what the description says) and my PC does not have bluray reader. Will I be able to download it from gog.com or Steam using cd-key that came with the game?

Comment: At least with most of the games, with your cd-key you can download it using steam. The game gets registered on your steam account.

Comment: The PC version of the game should be on DVDs, not Blu-Rays, so you should be fine even without the download. You can see on the box cover picture on amazon that is says "PC DVD-ROM". I doubt too many people have Blu-Ray drives in their PC and I know no PC game released on Blu-Ray. Only console games are on Blu-Ray as far as I know.

Comment: Not sure really: Here is the link http://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B00KRGA72I 
Although on the box says PC-DVD, description mentions: "Un disco Blu-ray con el juego (DVD en PC)". I guess they should correct it ;-)

Comment: @R2D2 Wouldn't "DVD en PC" mean that the PC version is on DVD? They probably made one description for all versions to say "the game is on Blu-Ray (except on DVD for PC)", because the Xbox One and PS4 use Blu-Ray.

Comment: Yes, you might be right. I'll find out tonight.

Comment: Yes, these are DVD's. Unfortunately my DVD drive died. Had to download it from GOG.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[All retail versions of the Witcher 3 contain a GOG key](http://en.cdprojektred.com/support/gog-com-game-code-boxed-copies-of-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/):

> Each retail PC copy of Wild Hunt will contain an additional GOG.com game code for The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt. One can install and play the game without the game code and without becoming a GOG.com user.
>
> GOG.com game code grants access to a digital backup copy of The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt on GOG.com and to full software support, i.e. future updates, as well as all the additional content like the 16 Free DLCs, the FLAC & MP3 soundtrack, comics, wallpapers, art book, all voice over packs and more.

Comment: Fantastic! I was click away to get bluray drive :-)

Answer (score 0):

I asked CDProjekt (Witcher 3 support) directly and got following answer:

You will be able to download and install game, extensions, DLCs from GOG.com (using the GOG key included in box edition).
Also optical drive is not (and will not) be needed to play. Game can be run from GOG games library.
In addition the hardware requirements on the box does not contain any optical drive.